# Mercurial: change tag from local to global

Tags: mercurial, tags

I wanted to change a tag from being local to global by deleting and recreating it, but the global tag is not shown.

What I did was:
(at the tip of the repository)

```
hg tag -l v1
```

(some time later, still at tip, no more commits have been made)

```
hg tag -l --remove v1
hg tag v1
```

Now tag v1 does not appear in `hg tags` output; Mercurial has committed 2 lines to `.hgtags`, one with a revision number of all zeros, which indicates a deleted tag.

I solved this by editing `.hg/localtags` to remove all reference to v1 before `hg tag v1`. I could have edited `.hgtags` and re-committed but that would have left evidence of my incompetence (!!). Is there a correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you've found a bug in how Mercurial computes the tags! I think the work-around you've found is the only current solution.

I've entered this as [Issue3338](http://mercurial.selenic.com/bts/issue3338) in our bug tracker.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response. I should add: I was using version 1.8.4 so it is not a recent change.

Comment: @PeterHull: Yeah, nobody has touched this code in a long time. Many people haven't even heard of local tags, they're not a very used feature :-)